# When i remove the data, a new one appears. How can i make it so it stays empty?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api

I created a button that fetch data and place it in a field, i also created a remove button which deletes all the data in the field, but when I press the remove button, it works, but it automatically adds a new one (thats also part of my task, but not like that). If anyone can help me on how to make those fields to remain empty, would much appreciate.

```
    const fetchapi = async () => {
        try {
          await axios
            .get("https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/addresses")
            .then((response) => {
              setAllData(response.data);
              //console.log(allData);
              //console.log(setAllData);
              console.log(response.data);
            });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
        //return allData;
      };
      const removeElement = (index) => {
        const newData = fetchapi((_, i) => i !== index);
        setAllData(newData);
      };
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <div>
            <button onClick={fetchapi}>Fetch Location</button>
            {!allData ? null : (
              <div
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "#c7c7c7",
                  display: "flex",
                  flexDirection: "column",
                  padding: 16,
                  margin: 5,
                  borderRadius: 20
                }}
              >
                <p>
                  <strong>Address: {allData.street_address}</strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <strong>City: {allData.city}</strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <strong>Street Name: {allData.street_name}</strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <strong>Zipcode: {allData.zip_code}</strong>
                </p>
                <button onClick={removeElement}>Botao</button>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things wrong here:

First let's look at this line:

```js
const newData = fetchapi((_, i) => i !== index);
```

Your `fetchapi` function doesn't take any arguments, so the function being passed in here will do nothing.
Also, your `fetchapi` function is an async function, so this line would set `newData` to a Promise object.
Also also, even if you added an `await`, since your `fetchapi` function doesn't return anything (since you've commented out the line that would return `allData`), this would set `newData` to be `undefined`.

Next let's look at how you're setting `allData`, by looking at where you're calling `setAllData`.

You call it in your `removeElement` function, which handles a button click.

But you also call it inside your callback for when the GET request comes back with data, inside your `fetchapi` function, which `removeElement` also calls.

So when you click that button:

- `removeElement` is called
- `newData` is set to a Promise object, since you're calling the async function `fetchapi` without an `await`
- `setAllData(newData)` sets it to be that Promise object, which means things like `allData.city` end up being `undefined`
- inside `fetchapi`, the GET request is made, and once it comes back, the callback is run, and `setAllData(repsonse.data)` sets it to be the same data again

If what you're trying to achieve is to delete an element from the backend data, then your button needs to send some kind of POST request to delete that element on the backend. Then you can fetch the data again, and now it won't include the delete element. Or you can just remove the element from your data on the frontend, if you don't care about any other possible updates to the dataset.

Or if what you're trying to achieve is just to fetch the backend data once, and then delete elements on the frontend (without modifying the backend data), when your button handler should only be modifying your component's `allData` state, and not calling `fetchapi` at all.

Comment: Worked on it, and it works, thanks!